# Display Taxonomies from the query $args

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, args, taxonomy-terms

I'm using [this tut](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html) to create an AJAX filter with multiple custom taxonomies. Everything works fine with the filter, that's not the issue.

Now I want to show the selected taxonomies on the result. The filter creates a different query every time depending on your selection, so it queries tax x, or tax x,y, or whatever. I want to show those queried tags on the results.

With `get_terms();` I get all the terms that the queried posts have, but I only want the ones in the `$args`
The closest I've been it's with `$query->request;` where I get something like  `( ( lv_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (5) ) AND ( tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (21,27) ) )`

Can I get the names of those IDs from `$query->request;`? Is there any other way of displaying the `$args` ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: To clarify - are you trying to display a list of taxonomy terms instead of posts?

Comment: I'm already displaying a list of posts, but I want to show some kind of breadcrumb: "You are viewing tax 1 and tax 2"